# Statement (add width) not working javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add width to a div based on the screen size with this piece of code:

```
if ($(window).width() < 1100) {
    var variable1 = 0;
    var variable2 = $(window).width();
    var variable3 = 1100;
    while (variable2!=variable3) {
        variable1 += 1;
        variable3 -= 1;
    };
$(".screen").css("width","+=variable1");
};
```

But it is not doing anything. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

One of the issues is that `variable1` holds a value and you're considering the actual string  "variable1" in your `.css` command. In addition, you are trying to increase a value somehow in your `.css` JQuery statement which is not required here. You don't need to increase anything in the `.css` jquery command as the `variable1` value fully updates to the value required in your `while` loop.

```
  $(".screen").css("width",variable1 + 'px');
```

Comment: They're not really "implementing it as a string" versus a number. They're typing in the actual string `"variable1"` instead of using the *variable itself*. Whether the value of `variable1` is a number or a string doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: Good catch. @MikeC. I still believe including `+=` in the statement is not needed. It's already updating in the while loop. There's not enough code to really know the exact implementation though so the question is still a little ambiguous at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the string `"variable1"` instead of the variable `variable1`. To use the variable, concatenate it to a string like this:

```
$('.screen').css("width", "+=" + variable1);
```